# How to define types for the todo reducer without editing the code itself?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

Redux example todo app has todo reducer like this:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/reducers/todos.js#L23

ADD_TODO action works without the state, but TOGGLE_TODO requires the state. How can i write a flowtype for a reducer like that **without editing the code itself**?

https://flowtype.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBFIBMQwLwwBTQIZQKYBoYtgoBLcASlQD4YBvAKBhggHdSpgALDYs8AHRQAngAdcVRs2bAsEXDADkAQQAiqgPoAVAPKqdigFxNpzAE64oAVzNh6J081IJDREuTADn+B47wAPKFc+DyFcQJ9HaVAAW1EAG0tcFxgAMyx4+V9mAF9fWXklXQBxYoAZAFFtPQNjKNJUjGw8LwQYAEIUNBDBZ0ls6QtrWxYoHFwBvIGhmzspKJgBJeaCAZkQOMS8FPaVgViEpIRJ3wRcdKt4oOnLWdHxkzyp0EhYeCQIVCaxvC+AbQAuoQemAqChaPM2BxuLx3IIROJ+qYCgoVOpqvojDdhnY-mtFssfqsFnBECB0FYwGdUqQwMlgXDQQMAfk5KiSuUqrpMXVHDMRnsYlhROhYOD8e9yVAGfwmVEKKdzlhLtcovy7CtHgwpuFRCAzLBqcqrqSPkA

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "without editing the code itself." You need to add type annotations in some places for Flow to typecheck your code. Anyway, here are the types I came up with for your example:

```
type Action = {
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: number,
  text: string,
} | {
  type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
  id: number,
};

type State = {
  id: number,
  completed: boolean,
}
```

Here's the complete [tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQN4CgpSiQBcUA5DACKUD6AKgPKUNkA0+UiAJqagK4BbAEYQATuwLAIAD2CkAzsFGJUAc3YBfKAB8cHIhFJlGAcRMAZAKL0mLCZx5R+wsZoDcuXAagBlYAEMpTD0Cbl5BEXEOOGQBMAAbCClHIWRkRP9UTU8Y1EVCZC5kYIAKRUDDXwCpVih-BBRUUngkNABKUj8KzAA+EKh5AHdEYDgACygS+tbUADoDNv6COH95aApqG2YyYg4CAlEkvlF0PH3zh1JpxtnuewvCGTk6hrR5p-uLmLjE5NIAM388TWe32GlBKzW5FMFmsjG2uweiH+k3KUluXCgAEIMFhrm9uIszg8oIdgMd0GiIKCCOCaaSjiclhdZqyqZ9zt8EkkII4sVTZlzfrz6eDzlwIIC+PE5PSyRSBtVqbTcHTcvlgIVkPJSlTmqJRP4QAAeLpSPpYADaAF1avimrBXqhFhg+sShiNxpN7fNwBAiRDVusqLR4SxERd5UzLfSCKzZuzYwUiiU+KgJf8VLy7U62vTrYGocYGGYrFtw3LGZSlbMBP4wCVgL0k5qU8AczM8w8u-sM-5pbKHlHqxUOOC6TIwMhRE2+wPk9qgA). I don't think there is any good way to express to Flow that you will only pass `undefined` to `todo` when `action.type` is `ADD_TODO`. It would be better to restructure the code somewhat.

Keep in mind that Flow is not a silver bullet. It is a great tool for preventing bugs and making development easier, but in return for the static checking you have to give up some patterns that it cannot understand. You will find that you often have to structure your code around what Flow can understand (incidentally, I believe this leads to better design choices and makes it easier for humans to understand as well). Type safety isn't free, and this is a fundamental limitation of all typecheckers. So, don't expect that it will be able to check everything without you "editing the code itself."

Comment: I was hoping that i could define what kind of state the function accepts depending on the action. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: You could use disjoint unions (similar to what I used for the Action type) that includes both the state and the action. If the action is ADD_TODO then the state would be left out. That's probably overly verbose and confusing though. I don't know of a great solution besides restructuring the code. Beware of any answer that involves the `declare` keyword -- it will appear to typecheck, but you'll lose safety because Flow trusts `declare` blindly.